# I don't know javascript algorithm problem! (codewars problem)

Tags: javascript

I have a simple question about JavaScript algorithm

https://www.codewars.com/kata/56747fd5cb988479af000028/train/javascript

I'm solving this problem. The explanation of this problem is to extract two letters from the middle of the odd-numbered character

What I'm curious about is

```
function getMiddle(s) {
//Code goes here!
let answer = "";
if (s.length % 2 !== 0) {
answer += s[Math.floor(s.length / 2)];
} } else {
answer += s.slice(
(Math.floor(s.length / 2 - 1), Math.floor(s.length / 2 + 1))
);
}
return answer;
}
console.log(getMiddle("test"));
console.log(
"test".slice(
Math.floor("test".length / 2 - 1),
Math.floor("test".length / 2 + 1)
)
);
```

Is the return value from the getMiddle function different from the console.log('test'.slice~') in the end?

The difference is that one is the return value of the function and the other is just taken directly from the console, but I don't know why it's the same code, but the value is differentcrying

please help me

Comment: You have some mismatched curly braces. Please may you make sure the code is a [mcve]?

Comment: It is a good habit to properly indent your code. Makes it easier to see what it is doing (also for you), and to debug it.

Comment: with the extra prentices its basically slicing the fist char on the string and ignoring all the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the function you have wrapped the pair of indices in parentheses:

```
answer += s.slice(
    (Math.floor(s.length / 2 - 1), Math.floor(s.length / 2 + 1))
//  ^                                                          ^
);
```

Those parentheses will trigger an evaluation of what is between them, and that means the comma is then interpreted as a [comma-operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). The result of that operation is then a single number that is passed as argument to `s.slice`. So you are actually calling `slice` with just one argument instead of two, and due to the comma operator, it is the second index that is used by slice. It is equivalent to `s.slice(3)`

In the second `console.log` you don't have those extra parentheses, and so there it works as it is intended.

*NB: I assume the extra closing brace just before `else` is a typo.*